# How to get a number out of this url in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url

```
http://nikerunning.nike.com/nikeplus/v2/services/app/run_list.jsp?userID=1413795052&startIndex=0&endIndex=-1&filterBy=all
```

I want to fetch `1413795052` number using regex in javascript, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var url = 'http://nikerunning.nike.com/nikeplus/v2/services/app/run_list.jsp?userID=1413795052&startIndex=0&endIndex=-1&filterBy=all';
var match = url.match(/userID=(\d+)/)
if (match) {
    var userID = match[1];
}
```

This matches the value of the userID parameter in the URL.

`/userID=(\d+)/` is a regex literal. How it works:

- The `/` are the delimiters, like `"` for strings
- `userID=` searches for the string `userID=` in `url`
- `(\d+)` searches for one or more decimal digits and captures it (returns it)

Comment: Thanks it worked.. also can you explain to me what does `/userID=(\d+)/` do?

Comment: Then how come it gets only the number `1413795052` but not `userID=1413795052`?

Comment: The whole matched string is returned in match[0], and all captured strings (the parts under parenthesis) are returned in match[x] where x is the number of the capture group

Answer (score 5):

This will get all numbers in the querystring:

```
window.location.search.match(/[0-9]+/);
```

Answer (score 3):

try it right here in stackoverflow:

```
window.location.pathname.match(/questions\/(\d+)/)[1]
> "7331140"
```

or as an integer:

```
~~window.location.pathname.match(/questions\/(\d+)/)[1]
> 7331140
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
var input = "http://nikerunning.nike.com/nikeplus/v2/services/app/run_list.jsp?userID=1413795052&startIndex=0&endIndex=-1&filterBy=all";

var id = parseInt( input.match(/userID=(\d+)/)[1] );
```